# Liferay - portlet title reloading

Tags: java, struts, liferay, portlet

I have trouble with portlet title. My portlet is created in struts framework. Portlet titles are set by Liferay UI manager (so the settings are stored in hsql script I guess, right?).

1. I choose language option;
2. After some action I expect to change portlet title depend on language version but it doesn't work; The changes are visible after reloading the page one more time;

I have tried to implement StrutsPortlet class and set title dynammically (renderResponse.setTitle) like this [Liferay: Set title name for view pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14133663/liferay-set-title-name-for-view-pages)  It also doesn't work. The changes are visible after reloading page one more time. Why the changes are not visible immediately? I have read (http://colab.mpdl.mpg.de/mediawiki/images/3/38/PortletsinAction_Final.pdf) that "*The setTitle method is defined only in the RenderResponse interface; you can only change the portlet title in the **render request-processing phase***". What it mean? Any suggest?

Comment: Please post your code. It is likely that you are setting the title before the language version is changed.

Answer (score 0):

You should use resource bundle for localization of portlet title.

**portlet.xml**

```
    <portlet>
    <portlet-name>test-portlet</portlet-name>
    ...
            <resource-bundle>content.test-portlet</resource-bundle>
            ...
</portlet>
```

**test-portlet.properties**

```
javax.portlet.title=Test Portlet
```

**test-portlet_sk.properties**

```
javax.portlet.title=Testovaci Portlet
```